# Getting Access Token on Pinterest

Tags: php, pinterest

I am trying to fetch pinterest access token through php curl.
But i am getting following in response

```
{"status": "failure", "code": 5, "host": "coreapp-ngapi-prod-0a010eba", "generated_at": "Wed, 26 Oct 2016 03:42:04 +0000", "message": "Method not allowed", "data": "405: Method Not Allowed"}
```

my curl is as follows

```
$clientId     = 'XXXX';
$clientSecret = 'YYY';
$authCode     = 'ZZZ';

$uri = 'https://api.pinterest.com/v3/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=' . $clientId . '&client_secret=' . $clientSecret . '&code=' . $authCode;


$ch = curl_init( $uri );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
if( curl_errno($ch) ){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
echo 'Response : ' . $response;
exit;
```

Comment: Use the get method instead of post method

Comment: same response with get method also

Comment: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/token?
    grant_type=authorization_code&
    client_id=12345&
    client_secret=6789abcd&
    code=xyz1010

Comment: check this
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/

Comment: @NavjotSingh, v3 is pinterest latest version, I tried with v1 but no luck.

Comment: use the response_type=token in first call to get the access token and use this access token for all other calls

    https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?client_id=4779055074072594921&redirect_type=js&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.pinterest.com%2Ftools%2Faccess_token%2F&response_type=token&scope=read_public%2Cwrite_public

Comment: Yes it returns access token when i set response_type = token, But is it right way to get it? It is not referred at Pinterest API.

Comment: Its the right way. in the pinterest api expoler its directly get the access token and used.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much @NavjotSingh